# np.exp()について

Tags: python, numpy

`np.exp()`が指数関数ということは調べて分かったんですがいまいちどういうことかわかりません。

```
a = np.array([0.3, 2.9, 4.0])
exp_a = np.exp(a)
```

`print(exp_a)`の出力が`[  1.34985881  18.17414537  54.59815003]`になぜなるのかよくわかりません。
教えてもらえるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x が数のとき、`numpy.exp(x)` は e の x 乗を返します。 e は[自然対数の底](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8D%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%82%A2%E6%95%B0)と呼ばれる数で、大体 2.7 くらいです。なのでたとえば、`numpy.exp(0.3)` を計算すると e<sup>0.3</sup> ≒ 2.7<sup>0.3</sup> ≒ 1.3 くらいの数になります。

x が配列やリストのとき、`numpy.exp(x)` は x のそれぞれの要素に対して `exp` を計算し、結果を同じく配列やリストで返します。

ですから、`numpy.exp(numpy.array([0.3, 2.9, 4.0]))` は [ e<sup>0.3</sup>, e<sup>2.9</sup>, e<sup>4.0</sup> ] を計算することになり、これを小数に直すと [ 1.3…, 18.1…, 54.5… ] になります。

より詳しくは、 [`numpy.exp` のマニュアル](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html)をご覧ください。